# Git diff to show changes in CSS block across commits

Tags: css, git

I have a block of CSS here, part of a larger file:

```
.card-container {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 12.92em;
  height: auto;
  margin-right: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 4em;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 6px 6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 5vh;
}
```

I want to display the changes over the last 2-4 commits in this particular code block only.

git diff HEAD HEAD^ ./assets/css/app.css

will let me check the whole file

I also want to show each revision of the CSS, not just two. So HEAD, HEAD^, HEAD^^ and so on.

The output should show 4 different code blocks, ideally with the date and message of each commit.

I need to be able to focus on that code block with ".card-container".."padding-bottom: 5vh"; Where .. is a wildcard, and the two strings define the start and end of the code block.

Answer (score 1):

To show commits that add or remove lines that match `<regex>`:

```
git log -G'<regex>'
```

To show last `<n>` entries:

```
git log -<n>
```

To show commits that introduced a change to file(s) at `<path>`:

```
git log <path>
```

---

To get back to your needs:

> I need to be able to focus on that code block with
>   ".card-container".."padding-bottom: 5vh"; Where .. is a wildcard, and
>   the two strings define the start and end of the code block.

```
git log -4 -G'\.card-container {.*?}' ./assets/css/app.css
```

That should log all the commits out of the last four that introduced a change to the `.card-container` rule in `./assets/css/app.css`.

Comment: Hi,,, no, I want to zero in on that particular CSS code block. The CSS file is long and I need to get specific.

Comment: That's close to what I need. I'll change it over the next week, update and accept when it works 100%.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following one-liner:

```
git show HEAD~2:path/to/your/file.css | sed -n '/^.card-container \{$/,/^\}$/p'
```

The command

```
git show HEAD~2:path/to/your/file.css
```

will return the contents of the entire CSS file in question from two commits ago (`HEAD~2`).  Then, we can pipe this output into `sed` to extract only the CSS block you described in your question.

Using this approach, you would have to run the above one-liner once for each previous commit.  For four commits, this isn't a prohibitively large amount of work.

Comment: That's close to what I need. It returns: sed: -e expression #1, char 22: Unmatched \{ ... implying no changes. I tried with HEAD~20, and the same output. Maybe I changed a different part of the CSS. How are you specifying to stop at the end of the card-container block, with the } brace, I guess. Thanks, I will play with that.

Comment: The `sed` expression I gave, as far as I know, should target the text between `.card-container {` and the first `}`.  My answer is just printing source code; whether you have changes would be determined by you, when you look at the various blocks over the last 4 commits.

Comment: I can see the curly braces now. I think that'll work with some adjustment.

Comment: Sure, I have to check all the answers before I accept one, but I'll upvote.